# Is it possible to automatically ALLOW oAuth Authetication thru REST?

Tags: rest, api

Currently trying to automate our API calls and the first hurdle is the oAuth.

Current steps are as follows:

1. Post Code - (In REST, getting 302, but since user needs to allow, I am not getting the code in this step)
2. Click Allow button - (Manually clicking the button :( )
3. Get Code - (Manually getting the Code from the URL)
4. Post Access Token - (In REST, was able to generate token but only after getting the Code manually)

Currently, I was able to use REST Client to execute steps 1 and 4.
My target is to remove manual intervention or UI automation for faster runtime.
Is there a way to ALLOW the approval thru REST Client?

Comment: Think about it, if you automatically authorize an OAuth endpoint then you beat the whole purpose of OAuth which is to have an **explicit and consensual** auth request from an endpoint. It can't be done, a person must always willingly grant access to an app using oauth.

Comment: Hi @JavierSilvaOrtíz, I understand what you mean, but I am talking on an Automation perspective. Obviously since we are the one testing, we will grant access to an app we are trying to automate. It is a different matter if the API itself is being used by the client manually where in they can allow or deny the request.

Comment: Hi @PaulCo, you should edit your question to include the fact that it's in a *development* and *testing* environment and **not** for production use.